# How to make a mask for an image and turn it to different colors in PyQt6?

Tags: javascript, python, image, pyqt, pyqt6

I have the below image.

[image: image.png]

I make it a mask in javascript and this lets me turn the image to every color that I want. here is the code.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: darkgray;">
    <canvas id="theCanvas" style="background-color: lightgray;"></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
const theCanvas = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
const ctx = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
theCanvas.width = 150;
theCanvas.height = 150;
const image = new Image();
image.onload = drawImageActualSize;
image.src = "image.png";
color = "red";

function drawImageActualSize() {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.rect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
}
```

and this gives me the below image.

[image]

now I want to do the same job in `Python` using `PyQt6` but how should I make an image mask in `pyqt6`?

so far I did this below code.

main.py

```
from sys import argv
from sys import exit as ex
from pathlib2 import Path
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QTimer
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPaintEvent, QPainter, QImage, QPen, QColor, QBrush


class PaintWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        )
        self.image = QImage(str(Path(Path(__file__).parent, "image.png")))
        self.image.scaledToWidth(150)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(17)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent | None) -> None:
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(169, 169, 169), 0, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(169, 169, 169), Qt.BrushStyle.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        rect = QRectF(0, 0, self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        painter.drawImage(rect, self.image)
        painter.end()
        return super().paintEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setup_ui()
        self.show()

    def setup_ui(self) -> None:
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.main_window_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.painter_widget = PaintWidget()
        self.main_window_layout.addWidget(self.painter_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.main_window_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    ex(app.exec())
```

that gives me this.

[image]

I try this code

```
self.masking = self.image.createMaskFromColor(0, Qt.MaskMode.MaskInColor)

painter.drawImage(rect, self.masking)
```

but it turns everything to black and white and gives me this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve such effects, and it depends on multiple aspects, including how the source image is actually made of.

In your specific case, you have an alpha channel which is *fully* transparent, so you can use QPainter's composition modes, which are conceptually similar to those of the javascript canvas, but work in slightly different ways.

Your attempt doesn't work for a simple reason: the `createMaskFromColor()` only creates a basic monochrome bitmap (pixels are either 0 or 1), and such image should normally be used as a *mask*, not directly drawn.

One possibility is to draw the image, then set the *clip region* based on the mask of the image alpha, and set the `CompositionMode_Multiply`.

Note that this will only work when the "border" is fully black, and it's not 100% accurate, as you'll clearly see a "red-ish" margin around the shape; coincidentally, this is also what you got from the javascript code.

```py
class PaintWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding
        )
        image = QPixmap(str(Path(Path(__file__).parent, "image.png")))
        self.image = image.scaledToWidth(
            150, Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation
        )
        self.setMinimumSize(self.image.size())

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent) -> None:
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(169, 169, 169))

        rect = self.image.rect()
        painter.drawPixmap(rect, self.image)

        mask = self.image.toImage().createAlphaMask()
        painter.setClipRegion(QRegion(QBitmap.fromImage(mask)))
        painter.setCompositionMode(
            painter.CompositionMode.CompositionMode_Multiply)
        painter.fillRect(rect, Qt.GlobalColor.red)
```

Note that I made some changes to your code; most importantly:

- `scaledToWidth()` *returns* an image, does *not* resize itself (note that it's named "scale**d**");
- it's normally better to use QPixmap instead of QImage when painting on screen; to slightly improve performance, you may create the mask in the `__init__` (converting QPixmap to QImage is a bit costly);
- using a 0-width pen with the same color as the brush to draw a colored rectangle is completely pointless: use `QPainter.fillRect()` instead;
- `QRectF(0, 0, self.image.width(), self.image.height())` is also pointless, as you can just use `self.image.rect()`;
- if you're overriding painting, you shall not call the base implementation (`super().paintEvent(event)`); returning it is also pointless, since it's implicitly `None`;
- considering the above, you can also simplify the code by creating the painter with the widget in its constructor, and avoid the `end()` call, which is implicit as soon as the function returns (since the painter will be garbage collected);
- there's no need to use a timer to update the widget, unless the contents actually change;
- it's also good practice to *not* call `self.show()` within the constructor of a widget, even if it's intended as a window;

Comment: This was not just a simple answer to my question but there were a bunch of tips I didn't know next to solving my problem. Thank you so much.